# How to change text on the last row created from ROLLUP

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb, rollup

I created this SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    orders.order_id AS "Nr. zamówienia",
    orders.order_date AS "Data zamówienia",
    products.name AS "Nazwa produtku", 
    products.price AS "Cena produtku", 
    orders.count AS "Ilość", 
    clients.client_id AS "Numer klienta",
    clients.first_name AS "Imię", 
    clients.last_name AS "Nazwisko",
    SUM(orders.count * products.price) AS "Cena Łączna"
FROM orders
INNER JOIN clients ON orders.client_id = clients.client_id
INNER JOIN products ON orders.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE orders.client_id = 215234
GROUP BY orders.order_id WITH ROLLUP
```

and get this result:
[resuult of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTXgO.png)

Is it possible to change last row to only show "Sum:" in the column "Nazwisko", but not the doubled last row?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822666/how-can-i-replace-null-category-titles-in-mysql-rollup-function

Comment: Ok, but not all my columns are null

Comment: joins and group by can be a bit tricky. Sometimes you need to group by _before_ joining.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text/data. Post your current and expected result as text tables. Also tell us if all `_id`-columns are primary keys in their tables. Ideally create a fiddle with sample data.